# How to mock global objects declared in sagas while writing jests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga

I have my saga code as:

```
//Start
Let x= {};

Function* A(){
   x=yield call(apiCall) //returns Object

   yield call(B)
}

Function* B(){

   if(x.value===true){

     //Certain actions

   }

}
```

How to write jest for `function* B`. Whenever I try to do `Sagas.B.next()` it gives me **undefined**. How to mock the value of `x` so that I can go into the if block in `B`.

Comment: `x` is *local*, not global. You can export it for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks